# Perturbing distributional strategies on a measure zero set

Tags: game-theory

In the context of a Bayesian game, $\Gamma = \left< (\Theta_i,\mu_i)_{i \in N}, (A_i)_{i \in N}, (u_i)_{i \in N}\right>$ where type of agent $i$ is drawn from $\Theta_i$ according to a probability measure $\mu_i$, recall that a distributional strategy $\sigma_i$ is a probability measure on $\Theta_i \times A_i$ such that the marginal on $\Theta_i$ is $\mu_i$.

Let $(\sigma_i)_{i \in N}$ be a Bayes Nash equilibrium of $\Gamma$.

If $\sigma_i^{'} = \sigma_i$ almost everywhere, is $(\sigma^{'}_{i})_{i \in N}$ also a Bayes Nash equilibrium of $\Gamma$?

Comment: Indeed, yes---the players' expected payoffs do not change.

Comment: Thank you. The fact that this is not true for behavioural strategies $\beta_i: \Theta_i \rightarrow \Delta(A_i)$ has always bugged me. I consider the question closed.