# Existence of Bayes Nash equilibria in behavioural strategies

Tags: mathematical-economics, game-theory

Follow up from this question: [Perturbing distributional strategies on a measure zero set](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/35885/perturbing-distributional-strategies-on-a-measure-zero-set?noredirect=1#comment54936_35885)

In the context of a Bayesian game, $\Gamma = \left< (\Theta_i,\mu_i)_{i \in N}, (A_i)_{i \in N}, (u_i)_{i \in N}\right>$ where type of agent $i$ is drawn from $\Theta_i$ according to a probability measure $\mu_i$, recall that a distributional strategy $\sigma_i$ is a probability measure on $\Theta_i \times A_i$ such that the marginal on $\Theta_i$ is $\mu_i$.

For any distributional strategy $\sigma_i \in \Delta(\Theta_i \times A_i)$, we can define a behavioural strategy as regular conditional distributions
$\beta_i(B,\theta) = \sigma(B \vert \theta)$ where $B$ is a measurable subset of $A$. Note each distributional strategy corresponds to an equivalence class of behavioural strategies.

> The question is as follows:
>
> Suppose $(\sigma_i)_i$ is a BNE of $\Gamma$. Does there exist a set of behavioural strategies $(\beta_i)_i$ where $\beta_i(B,\theta_i) = \sigma_i(B \vert \theta_i)$ such that they constitute a BNE?

Comment: Under the only reasonable way to define expected payoff for behavior strategies, yes.